# backbone.js with jsonp

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, jsonp

After spending hours searching for a solution, I'm finally posting the question here guys. Let me know my degree of stupidity :).

Here's the code:

```
Model and collection:
var app = app || {};
var metricsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var MetricsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model:metricsModel,
  sync: function(method, collections, options) {
    options.dataType = "jsonp";
    return Backbone.sync(method, collections, options);
  },
  url:<url>
});

View:
app.CommitmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize:function(){
    app.metrics = new MetricsList();
    app.metrics.bind("change", this.render, this);
    app.metrics.fetch({
      success: function(collection,response) {
        console.log("fetch successful" + response);
      },
      error: function(collection,response) {
        console.log("error" + JSON.stringify(response));
      }
    });
    app.metrics.on('all',this.render,this);
  }
});
```

> Result: error{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}.

The error callback is getting called always. I don't have much control over the backend. Just made sure the following checks are done:

Server responds with the correct JSON - An array of JSON objects. Tested on FF and Chrome.
JSON keys are strings.

How can I debug this further? Let me know please.

Comment: Can you check the HTTP request, error code that is sent ? With Chrome or Sagari, you can see that with the Web Inspector (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview).

Comment: @LaurentPerrin isn't it mentioned in the question? `"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"`

Comment: The value passed to the callback suggests that the query is OK, but that's not the actual HTTP request.

Comment: Is it your server, or an external one?  Remember, it needs to actually support JSONP for this to work -- it *shouldn't* return just raw JSON, it has to return JSON *wrapped in a Javascript function*.

Comment: @dbaseman The server is an external one but I know those people, so they will be able to tweak it. The server does return raw JSON. I'll ask these guys to return JSON within a javascript function. Will post here if that works. Thanks

Comment: The request should match the response -- it's worth reading the sections on JSONP in the JQuery docs:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

So it happens that the backend was returning a json object. The REST framework used in the backend is so flexible that all I had to do was replace json with jsonp in the URL.

Old URL : http:///format/json
New URL : http:///format/jsonp

Here's the REST Framework
https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

Thanks @dbaseman for your suggestion/comment